# Asymptotic behavior of $\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(-|X|^\nu\right)\right]$ wrt the mean of the normal rv $X$

Tags: convergence-divergence, asymptotics, normal-distribution, hypergeometric-function, probability-limit-theorems

Here is a statement that I would like to prove:

> Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, 1)$. Let $\nu >0$, show that $$
> -\log \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(-|X|^\nu\right)\right] \quad\underset{\mu \to +\infty}{\sim}\quad \mu^\nu $$
>   where $f(x) \sim g(x)$ means $f(x) = g(x) + o(g(x))$.

I have checked numerically that it is always verified whatever $\nu>0$, but I cannot prove it.

**Attempt of proof:**
Here is what I have tried:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(-|X|^\nu\right)\right]
=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\mathbb{E}\left[|X|^{\nu k}\right]
\end{align}
We have, for any $p>0$
[[see here]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments)
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[|X|^{p}\right]
=
\frac{2^{\frac{p}{2}} \Gamma[\frac{1}2 +\frac{p}{2}]}{\sqrt{\pi}}
M\left(-\frac{p}2, \frac12, -\frac{\mu^2}2\right)
$$
where M is the Kummer function.
And we have [[see here]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Asymptotic_behavior)
$$
M\left(-\frac{p}2, \frac12, -\frac{\mu^2}2\right)
\quad\underset{|\mu| \to \infty}{\sim}\quad
\frac{\Gamma(1/2) \left(\frac{\mu^2}2\right)^{\frac{p}2}}{\Gamma(\frac12 + \frac{p}2)}
$$
Pluging these two together give
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[|X|^{p}\right]
\quad\underset{\mu \to +\infty}{\sim}\quad
\mu^p
$$
Now I would like to conclude that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(-|X|^\nu\right)\right]
&\quad\underset{\mu \to +\infty}{\sim}\quad
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\mu^{k \nu}
=
\exp\left(-\mu^{\nu}\right)
\end{align}
but I cannot because I have no control on the error term with respect to $k$ (in order to use dominated or monotone convergence arguments). Maybe this reference could help: [here](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_508.htm).

**Note 1:** I have also tried using the Delta method, but I did not succeed.

**Note 2:** In fact the statement that I need is a bit weaker:
$$
\log\left[C_\nu-\log \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(-|X|^\nu\right)\right] \right]\quad\underset{\mu \to \infty}{\sim}\quad \nu \log \mu
$$
where $C_\nu$ is a constant ensuring the quantity inside the outer log to be positive when $|\mu|>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an argument for $\leq$:

Fix $v>0$. Define $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f(y) = \exp(-y^v)$.  Then: 
\begin{align}
f'(y) &= -vy^{v-1} \exp(-y^v)\\
f''(y) &= [(vy^{v-1})^2  + -v(v-1)y^{v-2}]\exp(-y^v)
\end{align}
Notice that if $0 < v \leq 1$ then $f$ is a convex function over the domain $y \geq 0$. Further, if $v>1$, there is a threshold $\theta>0$ such that $f$ is convex over $[\theta, \infty)$.

#### Case $0 < v \leq 1$:

By convexity of $f$ for this case we get by Jensen's inequality: 
$$ E[\exp(-|X|^v)] = E[f(|X|)] \geq f(E[|X|]) = \exp(-E[|X|]^v) $$
Taking $-\log()$ of both sides gives: 
$$ \boxed{-\log(E[\exp(-|X|^v)]) \leq E[|X|]^v} $$ 
In fact this holds for any random variable $X$ provided that $E[|X|]$ is finite. Notice that if $X$ is $N(\mu,1)$ and $\mu$ is large then $E[|X|]\approx \mu$.  This is because: 
$$ |X| = X - 2X1\{X<0\} \implies E[|X|] = \mu - 2E[X1\{X<0\}] $$
and $E[X1\{X<0\}]$ is very small when $\mu\rightarrow\infty$.

#### Case $v>1$:

Recall that $f(y)$ is convex over $y \in [\theta, \infty)$.  Define the event $A=\{|X|\geq \theta\}$. Then taking expectations conditioned on $A$ we get by a similar argument: 
$$ \boxed{-\log(E[\exp(-|X|^v) \:  |A]) \leq E[|X| \:  | A]^v} $$ 
Now when $\mu\rightarrow \infty$ we get $P[A]\rightarrow 1$ and also $E[|X|] \approx \mu$ for large $\mu$.

Comment: Intuitively, for the case $0<v\leq 1$, if you assume $E[\exp(-|X|^v)] = \rho_{\mu} e^{-E[|X|]^v}$, where $\rho_{\mu}>1$ is the "Jensen inequality gap parameter," and if $\rho_{\mu}$ stays bounded as $\mu\rightarrow \infty$, then $\geq$ also holds.  Similar for the case $v>1$ and conditioning on $A = \{|X|\geq \theta\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach to the lower bound (see my other answer for the upper bound).

Fix $v>0$, $\mu>1$ and let $X$ be $N(\mu, 1)$.  Define the event $B_{\mu} = \{\mu - \sqrt{\mu} \leq X \leq \mu + \sqrt{\mu}\}$ and note that $\lim_{\mu\rightarrow\infty} P[B_{\mu}] =1$. Since $\mu>1$ we know $\mu - \sqrt{\mu}>0$. By Taylor's theorem we have, if $x \in [\mu - \sqrt{\mu}, \mu + \sqrt{\mu}]$: 
$$ \exp(-x^v) \leq \exp(-\mu^v) + (x-\mu)(-v\mu^{v-1}) \exp(-\mu^v) + \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}\exp(-\mu^v)h(\mu) $$
where $h(\mu)$ also depends on $v$ and I will not write it out since I'm lazy...

Hence, conditioning on $B_{\mu}$: 
$$ E[\exp(-X^v) | B_{\mu}] \leq \exp(-\mu^v) +  \underbrace{E[X-\mu | B_{\mu}]}_{=0}(-v\mu^{v-1})\exp(\mu^v) + \underbrace{E\left[\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{2} | B_{\mu} \right]}_{\leq 1/2}\exp(-\mu^v)h(\mu)$$
where the underbrace values hold because the distribution of $X$ is symmetric about $\mu$, and conditioning on being in an interval about $\mu$ reduces the variance. We get: 
$$ E[\exp(-X^v)|B_{\mu}] \leq \exp(-\mu^v)[ 1 + (1/2)h(\mu)] $$
Taking the $-\log(\cdot)$ of both sides gives
$$ \boxed{-\log(E[\exp(-X^v)|B_{\mu}])\geq \mu^v - \log(1 + (1/2)h(\mu))} $$
and if someone is less lazy than me, that person could likely show $\log(1+(1/2)h(\mu))$ is asymptotically negligible in comparison to $\mu^v$.

Then note that for large $\mu$ we have $P[B_{\mu}]\approx 1$ and $X=|X|$ with high probability, leading to the desired result.

Comment: The expression $[1 + (1/2)h(\mu)]$ can be viewed as a bound on the "Jensen inequality gap" that I mentioned in the comment to my first answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael for your detailed answer. In fact $h(\mu)$ is negligible in comparison to $\mu^\nu$ only for $\nu < 2$. But after doing a bit more simulations, I think that my claim was only true for $0 < \nu < 2$. Thanks!

Comment: My mistake. I made an error in the computation of $h(\mu)$. I cannot find a simple expression for $h(\mu)$ such that your first inequality is true for all $x \in [\mu - \sqrt{\mu}, \mu + \sqrt{\mu}]$.

Comment: I chose that interval arbitrarily, you could consider $x \in [\mu - \mu^{1/4}, \mu + \mu^{1/4}]$, or $x \in [\mu - z_{\mu}, \mu + z_{\mu}]$ for some positive function $z_{\mu}$. The nice thing about making the interval size grow to infinity with $\mu$ is that the probability of falling in that interval goes to 1.  Eventually $f''(y)$ is nonnegative and decreasing in $y$ so for large enough $\mu$ we can use $f''(\mu - z_{\mu})$ as a bound in the Taylor theorem, where $f(y)=\exp(-y^v)$, so  $$f(x) \leq f(\mu) + (x-\mu) f’(\mu) + \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2} f’’(\mu - z_{\mu}),  \quad x \geq \mu-z_{\mu}$$

Comment: Thanks again. This has worked perfectly to finish the proof. Nevertheless, I found a counterexample in the case $\nu = 2$, so they must be a leak in the proof, but I cannot find where. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Below I have completed Michael's proof and **raise an issue**.

**1.** Recall that
$$
  f''(\mu) =
  \left[
    \mu^{\nu}
    + (1 - \nu)
    \right]
  \nu \mu^{\nu-2} e^{-\mu^\nu}
$$
I have chosen to focus at $x \in [\mu - \mu^\rho, \mu + \mu^\rho]$ for $0 < \rho <1$. And I have define
$$h(\mu) = 2 \nu (\mu - \mu^{\rho})^{2\nu-2} \exp(\mu^\nu - (\mu - \mu^{\rho})^{\nu})$$
such that for $\mu$ large enough, $\exp(-\mu^\nu)h(\mu) \geq f''(x)$ for all $x \in [\mu - \mu^\rho, \mu + \mu^\rho]$, and then the targeted inequality holds
$$
\exp(-x^v) \leq \exp(-\mu^v) + (x-\mu)(-v\mu^{v-1}) \exp(-\mu^v) + \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}\exp(-\mu^v)h(\mu)
$$

It remains to show that $\log(1+h(\mu)/2)$ is negligeable for all $\nu >0$ in comparison to of $\mu^\nu$. We have
$$
    \log(1 + h(\mu)/2)
    \sim
    \log(h(\mu)/2)
    =
    \log \nu + (2\nu-2)\log(\mu - \mu^{\rho})
    +
    \mu^\nu - (\mu - \mu^{\rho})^{\nu}
$$
And the result follows as
$$  (\mu - \mu^{\rho})^{\nu}
  =
  \mu^\nu (1-\mu^{\rho-1})^{\nu}
  =
  \mu^\nu (1+o(1))
  =
  \mu^\nu + o(\mu^\nu)
$$
Then following Michael's arguments, the result holds true for all $\nu >0$.

**2.** Nevertheless, I have an issue. For $\nu=2$, I know that $$
-\log \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(-|X|^2\right)\right] =
\frac13 \mu^2 + \frac12 \log 3 
$$
which contradicts the result because of the factor $1/3$ (convolution of a gaussian of variance 1, with a gaussian of variance 2). See with Maple

```
-log(int(1/sqrt(2*Pi)*exp(-x^2)*exp(-(x-mu)^2/2), x=-infinity..infinity));
```

My numerical simulations show that the asymptotical behavior is $\mu^\nu$ for $\nu < 2$, but nor for $\nu =2$. For $\nu > 2$, my simulations are too unstable to make any conclusion. Where is in the proof the reason to discard $\nu = 2$?

We can check with Maple that it works for $\nu=1$ (Maple cannot solve it otherwise)

```
> limit(-log(int(1/sqrt(2*Pi)*exp(-abs(x)^1)*exp(-(x-mu)^2/2), x=-infinity..infinity))/mu^1, mu=infinity);
1

> limit(-log(int(1/sqrt(2*Pi)*exp(-abs(x)^2)*exp(-(x-mu)^2/2), x=-infinity..infinity))/mu^2, mu=infinity);                                                                          
1/3
```

Thanks

Comment: I agree with the issue brought up in this answer. A rough application of the Laplace method indicates that, for $0 < \nu < 2$, $$-\log \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(-|X|^\nu\right)\right] \sim \mu^\nu$$ as claimed, but that for $\nu > 2$, $$-\log \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(-|X|^\nu\right)\right] \sim \frac{1}{2}\mu^2$$. This can be confirmed numerically in Mathematica using the code `\[Nu]=5;ListPlot[Table[{\[Mu],-Log[NIntegrate[E^(-Abs[x]^\[Nu]-(x-\[Mu])^2/2),{x,-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]},WorkingPrecision->10]]/(\[Mu]^2/2)},{\[Mu],10,100,1}]]`

Comment: (cont'd.) We can predict this bifurcation heuristically from the integral representation $$\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(-|X|^\nu\right)\right] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\mu^2/2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left\{-|x|^\nu - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + x\mu\right\}dx.$$ Focusing on the exponential in the integrand: When $\nu < 2$ the dominant balance in the exponential consists of the terms $-(1/2)x^2 + x\mu$, but as soon as $\nu = 2$ the term $-|x|^\nu$ enters the balance as well and thus starts contributing to the asymptotic.

Comment: (cont'd.) When $\nu > 2$ the $-(1/2)x^2$ term drops out of the dominant balance, leaving only $-|x|^\nu+x\mu$ and causing the integral to take on a new asymptotic character.

Comment: Thanks Antonio. I completely agree with your heuristical arguments, clearly confirmed numerically. But then what could be the flaw in the proof that as been given through the different answers of this topic?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with probability to say for sure, but the upper bound argument seems clear enough and the result is consistent with these asymptotics. The lower bound argument might be the one to look at.